# touchesForView in hitTest

Tags: iphone, uiview, touch, hittest, touchesmoved

I have a simple UIView used like container. 
If I write this code:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    NSSet *sTouches = [event touchesForView:self];

    NSLog(@"Touches %d", [sTouches count] );

    return self;
}
```

Doesn't work! I would like get touches count in hitTest() message, before touchesBegan()!
Is it possible?

I have this hierarchy:

```
UIView 
  +---> UIScrollView
```

When touch on my `UIView` (**single tap**) the container moves. When I double touch (two finger) on my `UIView`, the child `UIScrollView` doesn't work for **Zoom** (for example).
So I have think to catch touches number.

If touch number is equal to one, `hitTest` on my `UIView` container return "self". 
Else, if touch number is great to one ( == 2), `hitTest` return "scrollview" pointer.

In others words, I would like catch two finger event into hitTest() message/event.

Answer (score 1):

`hitTest` is used by the framework to determine which view is being hit, and thus which view to send the `touchesBegan`/`touchesMoved`/`touchesEnded`/`touchesCancelled` messages to. At the point `hitTest` is called, you can't tell.

Maybe you could explain what you are trying to accomplish, because this doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

Comment: Ok, I have this hierarchy:

UIView
   ---> UIScrollView

When touch on my UIView (single tap)  the container moves.
When I double touch on my UIView, the child UIScrollView doesn't work for Zoom (for example).
So I have think to catch touches number. If touch number is equal to one, hitTest on my UIView container return "self".
Else, if  touch number is great to one ( == 2), hitTest return "scrollview".